# StackOverflow em relacionamento bidirecional no JPA

Tags: java, spring, rest, relacionamento

Estou enfrentando esse problema com um relacionamento bidirecional, quando faço um put em Question para criar uma resposta ele faz a persistência, até aí beleza, mas se tento fazer um get ou mesmo na resposta da API me aponta um http 500, descobri que o problema é: Question contém uma lista de Answer, Answer contém uma Question, que contém uma lista de Answer, que contém uma Question .... tendendo ao infinito, alguém sabe como parar isso?

---

```
@Entity
public class Question extends BasicForum {

    private String title;
    private Integer views;

    @OneToMany(fetch= FetchType.LAZY, cascade= CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "question")
    private List<Answer> answerList;

    public void transformAnswerInList(Answer answer){
        List<Answer> answers = getAnswerList();
        answers.add(answer);
        this.setAnswerList(answers);
    }
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Answer extends BasicForum {

    @ManyToOne
    private Question question;

}
```

---

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(QuestionController.MAPPING)
public class QuestionController extends SuperController<Question, QuestionRepository> {
    public static final String MAPPING = "/api/questions";

    @Autowired
    private QuestionRepository repository;

    @Override
    public QuestionRepository getRepository() {
        return repository;
    }

    //Outros metodos ocultos

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/{id}/answers")
    public ResponseEntity<Question> postAnswer(@PathVariable("id") final String id, @RequestBody Answer answer){
        Question question = repository.findOne(id);
        question.addAnswer(answer);
        answer.setQuestion(question);
        return super.update(question);
    }
}
```

---

Estou usando Generics e liquibase, não sei se pode ser isso. Obrigado desde já.

Comment: O seu probelam me parece ser com a serialização. Ou seja, é na hora de converter uma Question ou Answer para um formato de String. No seu caso, em que formato a saída deveria estar? JSON? XML? HTML? Qual é o componente, classe ou configuração que faz essa conversão?

Comment: Aliás, se me permite o trocadilho, se você tem um problema com Questions e Answers, o resultado é StackOverflow. :)

Comment: kkkkk boa, o formato de saída deveria ser JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

esse problema acontece, quando o Spring tenta serializar o objeto para JSON, e como existem referencias circulares, ele joga uma exception indicando isso, para você resolver esse problema, você normalmente tem 2 opções, sendo essas:

1 - Você pode anotar um campo para ser ignorado na serialização com @JsonIgnore, nesse caso seria na lista de answer ou no Question.

2 - Você pode criar um serializer customizado do Jackson e você formata a serialização para te atender.

Obs: Você pode ainda tentar usar 2 annotations, mas não é certo de resolver esse problema.

```
@Entity
public class Answer extends BasicForum {

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    private Question question;
}

@Entity
public class Question extends BasicForum {

    @OneToMany(fetch= FetchType.LAZY, cascade= CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "question")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Answer> answerList;
}
```

Comment: Nesse caso o problema é que o json ignora as referencias da outra entidade, e eu preciso apresentar essa informação ao usuário no front :/

Comment: Ok, no caso então não tem escapatória, vai ter que criar serializer customizado do Jackson, já colocou as 2 annotations que eu falei?

Olha esse link, ele ensina como criar serializer customizado, http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization.

Comment: Usei, apenas do lado de answer, nesse caso resolveu em partes, pois Question daí fica com o array de answer normalmente, mas em Answer eu perco a referencia de Question no Json, vou tentar usar um Serializer, obrigado pela força.

Comment: De nada, não esquece de favoritar aahhahaha :p

Comment: Haha, já está feito